# Как убрать знаки перед значениями, после перевода с помощью bin(), oct(), hex()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

каким кодом можно убрать эти знаки перед числами:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за ответы

Comment: num[2:] - можно так

Comment: @TigerTV.ru благодарю

Comment: @MaidLine Можно ещё переводить не функциями, а через format:  `f"{100:o}"`  `f"{100:b}"` `f"{100:x}"` Тогда префиксов не будет. Причём это даже в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) к Python предлагается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Официальная [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) по Python предлагает использовать функции форматирования чтобы сразу получить строки без префиксов.

```
>>> '%o' % 100
'144'
>>> format(100, 'o')
'144'
>>> f'{100:o}'
'144'
```

Ну и по аналогии `b` и `x` вместо `bin()` и `hex()` соответственно.